# How to save a file to a specific directory and choose the file's name in python?

Tags: python, image, file, save

As the title says, how can I save a file (in this case a previously selected photo) into a specific directory and also name the saved file (I want to name it with today's date - eg: 01-01-2016.jpg)?

Here's some of my code:

```
import os.path
import datetime
todays_date = datetime.date.today ()

def add_pic (pic):

    if not os.path.exists ("Pictures"):
        os.makedirs ("Pictures")
    photo_name = todays_date + ".jpg"
    pic.save ("Pictures/"photo_name)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

for this line:

```
photo_name = todays_date + ".jpg"
```

Plus, I'm not sure about the last line either, so pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to "convert a tuple or struct_time representing a time as returned by gmtime() or localtime() to a string as specified by the format argument.":

```
photo_name = todays_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') + ".jpg"
pic.save(os.path.join("Pictures",photo_name))
```

Also use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) for a cross-platform method of joining directory to filename.

As @Blckknght says in a comment: please note that `'%m-%d-%Y'` is something for which you can change order, e.g. `'%Y-%m-%d'` is a common variant.

Comment: You may want to point out that the exact argument to `strftime` can be whatever the questioner wants (`'%Y-%m-%d'` may be better in many situations).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.above solution should work.Mistake what your were doing was adding time value with string.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because `datetime.date.today()` returns a date object.  Try converting to string by calling the `.__str__()` method, the `.ctime()` method, or the `.strftime()` method.
See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects.